# jQuery event propagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-events

I'm trying to animate a div using jQuery, the problem is the animation doesn't "propagate" to its children (NOT REALLY SURE IF I AM USING THE RIGHT TERM, I'M SORRY"). Please take a look at my demo, when you hover on the green box, it does the code, but when you hit on the sample text, it goes off .. so it results to restarting the animation again.. hope I explained it right..

also, can anyone share their experiences on how did they master Javascript or its library like jQuery?.. I really want to be good on this specific field..

```
$('.js_boxFeature').on(" mouseenter", function () {     
    $(this).animate({
        "top": "-20px"
    }, "fast");
});


$('.js_boxFeature').on(" mouseout", function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "top": "0"
    }, "fast");
});
```

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ma3ph/2/)

Comment: there is no demo attached... also instead of just posting the link to demo... add the relevant code to the question

Comment: oh yes, i'm currently editing i'm sorry.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/58wRy/1/

Comment: what do u want exactly?it works fine for me!

Comment: See Arun's comment, and maybe add `.stop()`: http://jsfiddle.net/ma3ph/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware, you could use pseudo event `hover` in/out handler like this:

### DEMO

```
$('.js_boxFeature').hover(function (e) {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        top: e.type === "mouseenter" ? "-20px" : 0
    }, "fast");
});
```

Or using only CSS pseudo class `:hover`:

```
.js_boxFeature {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
    top:0;
    -webkit-transition: top 200ms linear;
    transition: top 200ms linear;
}
.js_boxFeature:hover {
    top:-20px;   
}
```

### DEMO CSS

Comment: wow, i saw the css sample, i know i've tried doing it before but didn't workout for me. can you share me some tips / advice on to be really good at this? I am coming from a "graphic/web designer" point of view. i'm really looking for ways to be good at this.

Comment: Best ressource IMHO: http://css-tricks.com/ done by a great guy (i meant done by great guys ;) )

Comment: ye i'm constantly looking at that site but it is more on css, what i really want is to be good at jquery.. any tips on this one? plz

Comment: My best advice is too learn javascript before going to jQuery, which is a javascript library. I don't have unfortunately any specific ressource for that other than reading the DOC

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be the use of [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseout) event instead of [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseleave)

```
$('.js_boxFeature').on("mouseleave", function () {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        "top": "0"
    }, "fast");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/58wRy/)

Comment: I'd just add stop() for better behaviour handling

Comment: Man , you are so fast. i'm not done editing on the format of my post. then i got answers now. thank you very much.. can you share tips / advice on how to master jquery? javascript? really want to be good at this.